# How to use ESI for fragment caching in Varnish, in Ruby on Rails app built on spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, varnish, fragment-caching

The basic  syntax is not working for me.
I would like not to store user specific information in my cache,
but want to cache rest of the page.
Please provide syntax to do that in Rails app built on Spree.

Comment: would have helped if you posted what you already tried

Comment: @Alexander Balabin : Thanks for the response.
I tried using easy_esi gem for esi include syntax in rails app.
It's <%= esi_render :partial =>'shared/signin' %> syntax works in rails app,
page loads properly after using it.  But how to handle this request
in Varnish to not cache it. I tried using
 set beresp.do_esi = true;
 if(bereq.url ~ "signin"){ 
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
}
in vcl_backend_response subroutine.
But it's not working out for me.
Varnish is still caching whole page.